# Clarifications regarding the AをBに。。。 construction

Tags: grammar, particle-に

I've read [Meaning and transitivity of ゴミ袋を手に立ち上がる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/20854/meaning-and-transitivity-of-%e3%82%b4%e3%83%9f%e8%a2%8b%e3%82%92%e6%89%8b%e3%81%ab%e7%ab%8b%e3%81%a1%e4%b8%8a%e3%81%8c%e3%82%8b) before, but i'm looking to confirm some things where AをBに(して)is not the case.

> 彼女の視線**を**一身**に**浴びて、私は身が縮む思いだった。
>
> basking my body under her gaze, I feel my body shrink.

Basking with 彼女の視線 on 一身?Is there a more intuitive way to read this it literally?

> 突如として、ザーザーと叩きつけるように降り出した雨は、これからの波乱**を**、私**に**予感させるに充分だった。
>
> all of a sudden, the disturbance following the sudden pouring rain, satisfies my premonitions.?

Simplifying as 波乱を、私に予感させるに充分だった... I am fairly sure 波乱を<-予感させる as 予感させる is made to be transitive.

Am I to to interpret 予感させるに充分だった as 予感させるに(は)充分だった (for the purpose of 予感させる, 充分! ) ?.

波乱を、私に予感させるに充分だった = the disturbance, for me, predicting it(the disturbance) is satisfactory?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [ゴミ袋を手に(adv phrase)]　立ち上がる (it)
>
> [視線を (DirectObject)]　[一身に (IndirectObject)]　浴びる (tv)
>
> [波乱を (DirectObject)]、[私に (IndirectObject)]　予感させる (tv)

I am not very sure what you mean by saying "波乱を<-予感させる as 予感させる is made to be transitive."

Isn't 予感させる transitive even if it's not in causative form? 波乱を予感する also stands. It's in the causative form because it says 私に.
波乱を**私に予感させる**
波乱を**私が予感する**

> Am I to to interpret 予感させるに充分だった as 予感させるに(は)充分だった (for the purpose of 予感させる, 充分! ) ?.

Yes, 予感させるに（は）充分だった, meaning that it was enough for the purpose of making 'me' predict it.

Comment: "Isn't 予感させる transitive even if it's not in causative form?",  regarding this i found that it's pretty hard to tell, so i just assumed the causitive was for purpose of transitivity this time. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/47565/transitivity-of-suru-verbs-and-the-causative-form-to-turn-intransitive-suru-verb. If that is not the case, would "雨は波乱を、私に予感させるに充分だった。literally be " the rain causing me to predict the 波乱 is 充分" ?  It feels kinda of awkward.

Comment: It's the rain that is described to be 充分 to make 'me' predict the 波乱.

Comment: ah i see thank you,  you have input regarding the transitivty of suru verbs?