# Why do you say 何々を上達させる and not 何々を上達する?

Tags: grammar, causation

As the title states、would it be correct ever to say 何々を上達する? Why do we need to use the causative here?

For example

> 日本語を上達させたいです。

Could this be

> 日本語を上達したいです。

Apologies if the sentences are incorrect.

Comment: Related: [Difference between 完成させる and 完成する (transitive usage only)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27454/5010) 上達する is an intransitive-only verb in modern Japanese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because 上達する is considered an intransitive verb that means much like 上手になる

> 日本語**が**上達**する**　==>　日本語が上手になる　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　日本語**を**上達**させる**　==>　日本語を上手にする

There are other intransitive する verb like 実現 for example.

> 夢**が**実現**する**　==>　夢が叶う
> 夢**を**実現**させる**　==>　夢を叶える